# want to create a cron job to play video file?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, nano

But its showing -->

no crontab for vishal - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab

any suggestions how to workout ?

Comment: did you save the file after editing in nano?

Answer (score 0):

When typing `cronteb -e` and you don't yet have a crontab installed for your account, it is the normal message printed when exitting the editor.
Type `crontab -l` and you will see your cron instructions.
Check your local mails (`mail` command) in case there was an error in the command your crontab try to execute.

For more information: `man 1 crontab` (the command to update crontab), `man 5 crontab` (the format of the crontab files).